# Centering Thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, centering

i'm trying to center a group of fluid thumbnails, but they always align left instead of center.

here's the jsfiddle that shows the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/4040newb/bVa2Z/3/

you may have to enlarge the output window to see the thumbnails side by side and observe the problem

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row-fluid">

        <ul class="thumbnails">

    <li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
</a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>

<li>
    <a href="photos for nothing.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="nothing">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="blank photos/blankthumb.jpg" alt="nothing">
    </a>
    </li>


</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: a fluid container (which is what you are using) means they will be flexible in its presentation and adapt to the width of the container they are in.  If you want to have a fixed container and center *it* then the thumbnails should follow suit.

Comment: no, i want it to adapt to size, but the problem is that when the window isn't quite big enough to ad a new row, the thumbnails that are there don't center. there is definitely a way to make it be both fluid and centering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center` like so:

```
.thumbnails { text-align: center; }
.thumbnails li { display: inline-block; margin: 0; float: none; }
```

The initial trouble was Bootstrap adds `.thumbnails li { float: left }` which throws off the alignment. Adding `float: none;` to override fixed it right up.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/bVa2Z/9/show/

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/bVa2Z/9/

Comment: that doesn't work. if you go in the display window of your jsfiddle and move the window wider and less wide, you'll see that the group of thumbnails don't center on the page.

Comment: Easier to see this page-centering stuff if you end your fiddle URLs with `/show/`: http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/bVa2Z/7/show/

Comment: @ajp15243 Thanks for the tip! I'd forgotten about the `/show/` URL parameter.

Comment: okay, but still, the problem remains. updating .thumbnails { display: inline-block; } and .container-fluid { text-align: center; } did not make the problem go away. try moving around the window to see what i mean.

Comment: @shshaw, the problem is still there, you can see it in ajp's show fiddle when you move the window back and forth.

Comment: Ah! The issue was a `float: left` that was being added to the `.thumbnails li`. It's fixed now: http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/bVa2Z/8/show/

Comment: nice! looks great! how do i get the thumbnails to space out a little bit and not be right next to each other? do i set a margin on the thumbnails?

Comment: @user2989343 Make sure you add padding to both the left and the right `.thumbnails li { margin: 0 20px; }` to give equal spacing and keep them aligned.

Comment: nice! it's all working. thank you, this issue has been hanging over me forever.

Comment: Glad it's working! Sorry for the back & forth, but next time you may want to add a more detailed description or an example of what you want the end result to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your li's are block elements and therefore will fill the width of  their container and not sit next to each other.

You'll need the following CSS:

```
.thumbnails {text-align: center; }
.thumbnails li {display: inline-block; margin:0 }
```

You'll need CSS to position them in the centre. [Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVa2Z/5/).

Comment: that also doesn't work. if you go in the display window of your jsfiddle and move the window wider and less wide, you'll see that the group of thumbnails doesn't center on the page.